# Understanding the difference methods of malloc

Tags: c

Kindly, can someone explain to me the difference between the following two declarations of `n*n` Matrix.

```
int **Matrix;    
Matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
```

and

```
Matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); // without pointer
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How is `Matrix` declared?

Comment: There seems to be no n*n matrix in any of the statements. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: One is allocating space for an array of `int` pointers, the other for an array of `int`s. On most 32 bit machines, that's the same amount of space. But if you allocate `int`s and `Matrix` is declared as `int**` (pointer to pointer to `int`) on a 64 bit machine, you're about to have a bad day, roughly around the time you write to element `n / 2 + 1`. Other way around (allocating for pointers, using as `int`) you'll just waste memory at worst on all architectures I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes, I apologize .. I forgot to add the declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is wrong because you are allocating space for `int`s and not for pointers, on a 64bit system (*or where `sizeof(int) < sizeof(void *)`*) it will cause undefined behavior because the code will access memory beyond that allocated with `malloc()`.

Perhaps what you saw was

```
int *matrix;
matrix = malloc(n * n * sizeof(*matrix));
if (matrix == NULL)
    abort_malloc_failed();
```

which allocates a *n*×*n* "*matrix*" of contiguos integers, you cannot access this with two index notation however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I then access every element in this Matrix, i.e. using Matrix[i][j] ?

Comment: Using the first option you posted you can. But, you never check whether `malloc()` returned `NULL`, do it.